# how can I fix this problem I tried search for the match route but it doesn't show any thing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

**this my single product page**

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import Rating from "../components/Rating";
    import Product from "../Data";
    import { Row, Button, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card } from "react-bootstrap";
    // import PropTypes from 'prop-types';*
```

**This where I tired to find the match id and render the product with match id**

```
    const Products = ({match}) => {
      const product = Product.find((p) => p._id === match.params.id);
      return (
        <>
          <Link className="btn btn-dark my-3" to="/" />
          Go Back
          <Row>
            <Col md={6}>
              <Image src={product.img} fluid />
            </Col>
            <Col md={3}>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Rating
                  value={product.Rating}
                  text={`${product.numReviews}`}
                />
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <p>Description:{product.desc}</p>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <p>price: $ {product.price}</p>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </Col>
            <Col md={3}>
              <Card>
                <ListGroup variant="flush">
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Row>
                      <Col>Price:</Col>
                      <Col>
                        <strong>$ {product.price}</strong>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Row>
                      <Col>Status:</Col>
                      <Col>
                        {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out Of Stock"}
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Button
                      className="btn btn-primary"
                      type="button"
                      disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                    >
                      Add To Cart
                    </Button>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </>
      );
    };

    

export default Products;
```

**This is my single product screen**

```
import Products from "./pages/Products";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-3">
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route  index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="product" element={<Products />} />
            <Route path=":id" element={<Products />} />

          </Routes>
        </Container>        
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

In react-router-dom v6 the `Route` components no longer have route props (`history`, `location`, and `match`), and the current solution is to use the React hooks "versions" of these to use within the components being rendered.

In other words, `props.match` is undefined. This should also be clear since no props are passed to `Products`.

```
<Route path=":id" element={<Products />} /> // <-- no props passed to Products
```

## Solution

Use the [`useParams` hook](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams) to access the `id` route path param in the `Products` component. Don't forget that `Array.prototype.find` can potentially return undefined if no element matches the predicate, so your UI code should handle this case. (*avoids "undefined access of X" exceptions*)

Example:

```
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Products = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const product = Product.find((p) => p._id === id);

  if (!product) return "No matching product found.";

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="product/:id" element={<Products />} />
</Routes>
```

Your product page:

```
const {id} = useParam() // we can destructure out the id

const fetchProduct = async (id) => {
    const resultFromServer = await fetch(`url/${id}`)
    const dataFromServer = await resultFromServer.json()
    // with the data, now we can store it in useState or Context api
    // depends on your implementation, and show it to the client
}

useEffect(() => {
    if(id) fetchProduct(id) // Fetch product based on url id
},[]);
```

Comment: Sorry I can't understand this solution very well .

Comment: what  is exactly the  role of this function fetchProduct(id)

Comment: @ben kahla ahmed Hi, It's a function to fetch data, I have added more info for you to understand, feel free to ask for more clarification